# JAVA find largest and smallest word in string

Tags: java

```
    public class maxWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "“@2434 rfdfd4f fff“";
        System.out.println(maxWord(str));
        System.out.println(minWord(str));
    }

    public static String maxWord(String input){
        String[] str = input.split(" ");
        if (str.length==0) return null;
        String longest=" ";
        for (String word:str){

            if (word.length()>longest.length()) {
                longest=word;

            }
        }
        return longest;
    }

    public static String minWord(String input){
        String[] str = input.split(" ");
        String shortest=" ";
        for (String word:str){
            if (word.length()<shortest.length()) {
                shortest=word;

            }
        }
        return shortest;
    }
}
```

i have 2 methods here and they are almost similar but minWord doesn't show the smallest word, where is the mistake?

actually don't undestand where is a problem, i hope you will help me

Comment: `String shortest = " ";` - it is already one character long before you enter the loop.

Comment: If you use IntelliJ, this may be useful for you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html
[Place the breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html#setting-breakpoints) at the `if` statement in the `minWord()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use streams in order to do it in one line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "This is a long sentence";
    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(string.split("\\s+"));

    String shortest = wordList
            .stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
            .orElse(null);
    System.out.println(shortest); //prints "a"

    String longest = wordList
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
            .orElse(null);
    System.out.println(longest); //prints "sentence"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `String shortest=" ";`  therefore, `shortest` has length = 1. You can simply give `shortest` a very long string, or even the input string itself:

```java
    public static String minWord(String input){
        String[] str = input.split(" ");

        String shortest=input; // so shortest is initially the largest string

        for (String word:str){
            if (word.length()<shortest.length()) {
                shortest=word;

            }
        }
        return shortest;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the first string in the array as "minimum length" because the initial value " " is only length 1 and shorter than the other ones.

For example:

```
private static String shortest(String test) {
    String[] words = test.split(" ");
    String shortest = null;
    for(String word : words){
        if(shortest == null){
            shortest = word;
        }else  if(word.length() < shortest.length()){
            shortest = word;
        }
    }
    return shortest;
}
```

Or without if in the loop:

```
private static String shortest(String test) {
    String[] words = test.split(" ");
    String shortest = words[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < words.length;i++){
        if(words[i].length() < shortest.length()){
            shortest = words[i];
        }
    }
    return shortest;
}
```